# How to get an attribute value as Model instance in PHP ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I am trying to achieve something that should be simple but seems impossible in PHP ActiveRecord.

In the simplified example I created, I have two models, Person and Exchange, and two tables, `people(id, name)` and `exchange(id, user_from_id, user_to_id, comment)`. `exchange.user_from_id` and `exchange.user_to_id` have a foreign key constraint referencing `people.id`.

So when I run the following code:

```
$exchange = Exchange::first();
echo $exchange->user_from_id;
echo $exchange->user_from_id->name;
```

I would expect the first `echo` to fail and the second one to succeed. Instead, the first one succeeds and prints the litteral value of `exchange.user_from_id` and then obviously the second one generates a "Trying to get property of non-object" warning.

The result is the same with or without adding the following to Exchange:

```
static $belongs_to = array(
    array('user_from_id', 'class_name' => 'Person'),
    array('user_to_id', 'class_name' => 'Person')
);
```

What should I change in my code to make it so that `$exchange->user_from_id` returns an instance of the Person class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had misunderstood how BelongsTo work. I thought it somehow bound a property of a Model, corresponding to an attribute, to a different Model, but I realise now it creates a new property, which you then have to explicitely associate with an attribute using the `foreign_key` option.

Concretely, this is what I had to add to the Exchange:

```
static $belongs_to = array(
    array('user_from',
          'class_name' => 'Person',
          'foreign_key' => 'user_from_id'),
    array('user_to',
          'class_name' => 'Person',
          'foreign_key' => 'user_to_id')
);
```

Then, using this code:

```
$exchange = Exchange::first();
echo $exchange->user_from;
echo $exchange->user_from->name;
```

I finally got what I expected: a fatal error on the first `echo` and the second one printing `people.name` where `people.id = exchange.user_from_id`.

This also made it possible to use eager loading of the two `people` objects with:

```
$exchange = Exchange::first(array('include' => array('user_from', 'user_to')));
```